# cloudflare Durable Objects update object value

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Halo! I'm recently diving into cloudflare Workers, especially Durable Objects. I could make a simple request which `put` a js object into the assigned key. Let's say the key is `key0`, and the put object value is `{"fieldA": "val0", "fieldB": "val1"}`. In this case, how can i update the field-value of `fieldA` without removing `fieldB`? I've tried simply executing `put("key0", {"fieldA": "newVal0"})` and it has kept removing `{"fieldB": "val1"}`.

Of course it is a common behaviour in js operations, but i cannot find out anything like `~["key0"]["fieldA"] = "newVal0"` in docs(maybe i'm missing sth). OTL

Hope this question reach to the gurus in the community! Thanks in advance [:

---

EDIT after the answers:

In theory, it would be wonderful if flare durable objects support and work just like a normal js object. Such possible worker feature feels like a killer app for the cloud db services, since the average cpu time is quite fast and flare also has super low pricing compared to other big bros. If it happens, i would eager to migrate everything into the flare platform [:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durable Objects' KV storage only supports get and put operations -- it doesn't have any sort of "update". So, you have two options:

1. get() the key, modify it, and then write the modified version back. This may sound inefficient, but keep in mind that commonly-accessed keys will likely be in in-memory cache. In fact, this get/modify/put implemented in your JavaScript is probably about as fast as any modification operation that Durable Objects itself could possibly implement built-in. That said, you probably don't want to use this approach with large objects, since the whole object has to be written to disk again after every update.
2. Split your object across multiple keys. E.g. instead of having the key `foo` map to `{"fieldA": "val0", "fieldB": "val1"}`, you could have separate keys `foo:fieldA` and `foo:fieldB`. Note that you can fetch all the keys at once using `storage.list({prefix: "foo:"})`. This approach is not as convenient but allows each field to be written separately to disk.

Comment: Bad news for me ]: `prefix` sounds really useful tho. It might run like a basic query in nosqls'. Thanks for details Kenton. Yours helped me a lot both in SO and cf forums [:

Answer (score 1):

`get` and `put` deal with whole JS objects, so if you want to change part of the object you should `get` it, update it using normal JS, and then `put` the entire object back.

Comment: Thanks Brett for ur fast reply! It did help me [: